# Add Image to StackPanel in programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to programmatically generate a `StackPanel` and add an `Image` to the `StackPanel`. Somehow I get an empty StackPanel. I do not see anything wrong with my code, and it didn't throw any exception:

```
StackPanel Sp = new StackPanel();
Sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

Image Img = new Image();
BitmapImage BitImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
    "/MyProject;component/Images/image1.png", UriKind.Relative));
Img.Source = BitImg;

Sp.Children.Add(Img);
```

**[EDIT]**

I tried another way to add the Image and it works. It intrigues me because they seems to me essentially the same thing:

The following code **WORKS** (show image):

```
Image Img = new Image();
Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
             "pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Images/image1.png"));
```

The following code does **NOT WORK** (image missing):

```
Image Img = new Image();
BitmapImage ImgSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
    "pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Images/image1.png",
    UriKind.Relative));
Img.Source = BitImg;
```

Why are they different??

Comment: Make sure the image file URI is correct and you also need to set the img.Width and img.Height property to expected value.

Comment: Are you adding stackpanel to some other panel which is already exist in ur xaml..? unless you add stackpanel to some panel it will not get rendered on screen.. make sure to add stackpanel to existing panel

Comment: set the width and height, but still, no image. The image is located in Images folder.

Comment: You're not forgetting to Add the sp to the Window somewhere, are you?

Comment: I'm also adding some other TextBlock and Buttons to the StackPanel. Everything else showed up fine, except the Image is missing...

Comment: "Missing Image" is very different from "Empty Stackpanel".

Comment: Hmm... the `pack://` notation isn't relative. Your original addressing should have worked though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
             "pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Images/image1.png"));
```

uses by default `UriKind.Absolute` and not `UriKind.Relative`

If you wish to user `UriKind.Relative` - URI should be in different format. Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)

Comment: THX :-) it is not funny because an exception was not detected when using a wrong string for the uri.

Answer (score 5):

No repro.

I Copy/Pasted your code to a Button handler and added 1 line:

```
  root.Children.Add(Sp);
```

Tip: Set a breakpoint at the end of this code and use the "WPF Tree Visualizer" to see if everything is where you think it is. It's the little looking glass in the Locals and Autos Windows.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seems to be the problem. I changed my code a bit and it work but I still don't understand. Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working fine

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/Assets/default.png", UriKind.Relative);    
BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);    
profileImage.Source = imgSource;
```

or

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/default.png", UriKind.Relative));
profileImage.Source = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your first code. At the end of that code you should add the StackPanel to your window or the grid inside the window. Also notice that the image's Build Action must be "Resource" and in your image URI ("/MyProject;component/Images/image1.png"), "MyProject" should be the name of your assembly and not the name of your project. Check your assembly name in the Application tab of the project properties.